# Fax Service From Windows Server 2008 Needs To Write To NAS (Net Drive)

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-attached-storage, fax

I want to allow the fax service from Windows Server 2008 to write incoming faxes to a remote NAS box via `\\nas-name\folder\path` or `\\192.168.10.100\folder\path` which fails due of access rights for the fax service executing user/account.

The executing user/account for the fax service is `NT_AUTHORITY\Network Service` I tried changing the executing user to active directory accounts and other local accounts but the service won't start up after that, so I guess I cannot change the executing user for fax services. On the other hand I can not add a LocalSystem account to my NAS box.

How can I make/force the fax service to write to the NAS box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Since our server, which receives the fax, is a *DomainController* I added DOMAIN\DomainController as an authorized user at the *FileStation*.

Now the server has write access, regardless the executing account. This can be a bit of a security issue, but I restricted the access to certain folders only.